# JavaScript code printing on another page

Tags: javascript, html

my javascript code keeps printing on another page when it is to print on the same page where it says resultado:
I have tried quite a bit to get it to work but wont seem to work i think its something to do with the function ".write"

Thanks in advance

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fatorial de um número</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function CalcularFatorial() {
    var numero = document.calc.numero.value;
    var fatorial=0; 
    var x=0;


    fatorial=numero;

 for(x=numero-1; x>0; x--)
{
 if (x!=1)
  window.document.write(x + " x ");
 else 
  window.document.write(x + "");

 fatorial=fatorial * x;
}

    document.calc.resultado.value += fatorial;
  }
</script>
```

```
<body onload="document.calc.numero.focus()">
<form name="calc" action="#">
  Digite um número: <input name="numero" type="text" size="4" onkeyup="CalcularFatorial()" value="1" /><br/>
  Resultado:  <input name="resultado" type="text" size="99" style="border: none; color: #FF0000; font-size: 16px" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe because you're submitting a form? The form tag is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: document.getElementById("#INPUT_ID").value += fatorial, i suppose you wich to write your result in the input, not in the document, am i correct ?

Comment: use  `.innerHTML` on an element instead of `document.write`

Comment: Sorry not fully understanding

Comment: not understanding sorry